# OperationalError at /admin/budget/expense/add/

Tags: python, django

When trying to save a new expense on http://localhost:8000/admin/budget/expense/add/ I recieve a OperationalError message saying:

no such table: budget_expense

I think it may be something relating to how my models.py file is set up:

```
from django.utils.text import slugify

# Create your models here.

class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True, blank=True)
    budget = models.IntegerField()

    def save(self, * args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Project, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class Category(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Expense(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

For more context this is what the error message looks like:

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/budget/expense/add/
Django Version: 2.2.5
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
no such table: budget_expense
Exception Location: C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py in execute, line 383
Python Executable:  C:\Python37\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.4
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\kobby\\Documents\\financio',
 'C:\\Python37\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Python37\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python37\\lib',
 'C:\\Python37',
 'C:\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Sun, 15 Sep 2019 20:00:54 +0000
```

I can connect to Django admin just fine and I've been able to add 'projects' however when I want to add 'expenses' that's when the error comes. Any suggestions as to why this may be?

Comment: Show us the view function that's being called.

Comment: You haven't run migrations.

Comment: If by views function you mean views.py this is what that file looks like          
```from django.shortcuts import render

def project_list(request):
    return render(request, 'budget/project-list.html')

def project_detail(request, project_slug):
    # fetch the correct project
    return render(request, 'budget/project-detail.html')```

Comment: I just ran migrations but it didn't work

Comment: Do you create migration with add table for Expense model before run migrations?

Answer (score 0):

At first you must create migrations for add tables ([documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-makemigrations))

Next you  must run migrations. It create tables in your database ([documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-migrate))

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys the Django doc is truly underrated. I found my answer in the ([documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/migrations/#adding-migrations-to-apps)). All I needed to do was run `python manage.py migrate --fake-initial` which basically detects initial migrations and marks the migration as already applied.